# Parse JavaScript SDK - Object ID is undefined

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

This is just baffling me so I'm hoping someone else knows the answer to this.

```
var Obj = Parse.Object.extend("Object");   // Create a new Object
var obj = new Obj();                       // Make an instance
var ID = obj.id;                           // Get the ID
console.log(ID)                            // This is undefined
obj.set("id", ID);                         // SOMEHOW in Parse this still actually                         
                                           // works and is correct after saving
```

I tried using .toString() because the id is a number and that didn't work either. Any ideas?

Comment: Just a guess - is set doing a POST/PUT to the server and the server side is generating the id??  If that's the case, the client side object would not have an id since it hasn't been persisted

Answer (score 0):

The object id is assigned after the object is saved and is thereafter part of that object...

```
var Obj = Parse.Object.extend("Object");   // Create a new Object
var obj = new Obj();                       // Make an instance
var ID = obj.id;                           // Get the ID
console.log(ID)                            // This is undefined
obj.save().then(function() {
    console.log(obj.id);                   // it will work here
});
```

Comment: Hmmm, that makes sense but it's still undefined after. I was trying to re-use the ID for a property for other objects. What confused me was the first set() worked, but for subsequent objects it was blank.

Comment: Does the Object class exist and have create permission for the user running this code?  The code is too simple to not work.

Comment: And before you start moving object Ids around, read up on pointers. I think you can (and should) write elaborate apps without ever referring to an object id.